# How can I get past privacy error when trying to launch the Sitecore default website https://xp0cm.localhost?

Tags: certificate

I am going through the sitecore developer fundamentals 10 tutorial and am on Track 5: Launch Your Sitecore Environment In Docker.  I have gone through the previous steps, setting up the environment, adding the http certificates, and starting the containers.  My containers are running and in my certs folder I have certificates for xp0cm.localhost but when I try to visit https://xp0cm.localhost in the browser, I get a Privacy error saying my connection is not private.

Answer (score 1):

Two things you should check:

1. Is the certificate's subject value mathing "xp0cm.localhost"?
2. Check certificate is also "Trusted" which means certificate is in "Trusted Root Certification Authorities" store.